# Heroku R10 error in Python app

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku

I'm having a problem running my Python app in Heroku. My app scrapes a website for weather data and performs a few calculations on it. Pulling the data doesn't take more than a few seconds. When I open my app, my logs show the output of my app, but my app page continues loading until I get an R10 error, then the app page crashes. I can run my app using a one-off dyno from the command line just fine. Here are my logs:

```
    2016-08-18T13:58:34.073915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python WebScraper.py`
    2016-08-18T13:58:40.982330+00:00 app[web.1]: http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx
    2016-08-18T13:58:41.005187+00:00 app[web.1]:           Station  Low Temp (F) Time of Low  Current Temp (F) Current Time  \
    2016-08-18T13:58:41.005202+00:00 app[web.1]: 0               0.0         0           74.3      8:49 AM  
    2016-08-18T13:58:41.005205+00:00 app[web.1]: Arkansas: no inversion and spray OK
    2016-08-18T13:59:34.319236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
    2016-08-18T13:59:34.319458+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2016-08-18T13:59:34.443283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2016-08-18T13:59:34.459932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2016-08-18T13:59:34.460745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2016-08-18T13:59:39.598773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python WebScraper.py`
    2016-08-18T13:59:46.087192+00:00 app[web.1]: http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx
    2016-08-18T13:59:46.099928+00:00 app[web.1]:           Station  Low Temp (F) Time of Low  Current Temp (F) Current Time  \
    2016-08-18T13:59:46.100543+00:00 app[web.1]: Ashley: strong inversion and no spray suggested
    2016-08-18T14:00:07.473438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=temperature-inversion.herokuapp.com request_id=c477a7b2-d755-475a-ad11-f857764386b6 fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2016-08-18T14:00:39.933670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
    2016-08-18T14:00:39.933712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
    2016-08-18T14:00:40.095100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2016-08-18T14:00:40.079022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2016-08-18T14:00:42.882673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=temperature-inversion.herokuapp.com request_id=c5ee4daf-9825-4c53-8f9c-852b9a3eaae2 fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2016-08-18T14:00:44.549938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=temperature-inversion.herokuapp.com request_id=f45183be-4b77-429e-91be-dfcf832ec3ca fwd="199.133.80.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku expects the `web` process to bind to `$PORT` within 60 seconds. You need to use a different kind of process (e.g., `bot`) in your Procfile and scale the different processes (similar to [Python Twitter Bot w/ Heroku Error: R10 Boot Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541027/python-twitter-bot-w-heroku-error-r10-boot-timeout))

Comment: Ah, right... that makes sense; Heroku is intended for hosting web applications, so it expects at least one web dyno to bind to $PORT. Your options seem to be 1) try running the script via the scheduler add-on 2) create a simple, "do nothing" script using a light framework like flask to satisfy the port requirement.